# How to use Django ORM to get all contacts and messages?

Tags: sql, django

I have been thinking about it the last 2 days, and I don't know how to do it.

Models:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Sender", related_name='sender_user')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Receiver", related_name='receiver_user')
    readed = models.BooleanField('Readed')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField('Time', auto_now=True)
    message = models.CharField('Message', max_length=255)
```

In the page I need a list of unique contacts (without mine) and count unread messages, order by date_time. For example, in the table we can see:

```
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| id | sender_id | receiver_id | readed | date_time           | message                  |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------------+
|  1 |         1 |           2 |      0 | 2013-05-10 17:53:53 | 14124141                 |
|  2 |         2 |           1 |      0 | 2013-05-10 18:13:16 | 2131231 abf        |
|  3 |         2 |           1 |      0 | 2013-05-10 18:17:29 | 52525252                 |
|  4 |         1 |           3 |      0 | 2013-05-10 20:00:52 | 12312312312              |
+----+-----------+-------------+--------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

In a page there must be 2 contacts:

```
3 | 1 unread

2 | 2 unread
```

All I did was to combine two fields, remove duplicate records and my id, but I think, it's not all. So, any work examples about views.py? Is it possible to do this with SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Are you grouping the messages in the table by receiver_id or sender_id? what is 'your_id', what messages messages are filtered by that (exclude message where you are the sender or receiver)?

Comment: In the table I am not grouping the messages. My id - 1, for example

Answer (score 0):

A Change on your model field 'readed' it must be a Boolean

```
readed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

You can implement a nice 3rd party Package

https://github.com/philomat/django-persistent-messages

Which Help you to do more with Your Messages App.

Comment: I want to do messages user to user,not notifications

Comment: @tim Okaies . please explore the models https://github.com/philomat/django-persistent-messages/blob/master/persistent_messages/models.py